# How to find and clear all selected values from dropdown elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 4 **dropdown** elements in my webpage. I intend to find all of these and change their **'selectedIndex' to 0** at once.

Currently I'm doing the following :

```
$("#ddl1")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
$("#ddl2")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
$("#ddl3")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
$("#ddl4s")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

Although this code works perfectly and fulfills my requirement but here I have to select each of them individually.

How can I select all of them at once and change their index to 0.

For instance, I was successful while doing the same for textboxes.

Here's what I did :

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('');
```

This clears all textbox values at once.

Using the same approach I tried the following :

```
$('input[type="text"]')[0].selectedIndex(0);
```

and also this

```
$('input[type="text"]')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

But it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? How can this be achieved?

Comment: something like `$('select option').eq(0).prop('selected','selected')`

Comment: Show us your related `html`

Comment: `$('select').find('option:first').prop('selected', true)`

Comment: $.each($('select'),function(k,v){
 $(v).selectedIndex = 0;
})

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1ea7sodw/1/

Comment: **Thank you all**. I tried all the solutions provided here by all which were indeed very helpfuI. I used **@Arun P Johny's** solution as my final go-code as I found it pretty straightforward and I also didn't have to modify my existing code.

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
$("select").each(function(){
    $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
});
```

Comment: code-only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [answer]

Answer (score 1):

1. the drop down list html tag is "select" element, not the "input" element.
2. You should add the name attribute for each dropdownlist (e.g. name="abc1")

Use the following code:

```
$("select[name^='abc']").attr('selectedIndex', 0)
```

3. name^ means the name attributes like have 'abc' characters, if the dropdownlist name attributes contains abc characters, all of these drop drop down list will take the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`$("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);`

You can use Common Selector like `class`...

```js
$('#id-btn').click( function() {
    $("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label class="custom-select">
    Select your favorite food:
    <select>
        <option>Sushi</option>
        <option>Blue cheese with crackers</option>
        <option>Steak</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</label></p>
<p><label class="custom-select">
    Select your favorite food:
    <select>
        <option>Sushi</option>
        <option>Blue cheese with crackers</option>
        <option>Steak</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</label></p>
<p><label class="custom-select">
    Select your favorite food:
    <select>
        <option>Sushi</option>
        <option>Blue cheese with crackers</option>
        <option>Steak</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</label></p>
<p><label class="custom-select">
    Select your favorite food:
    <select>
        <option>Sushi</option>
        <option>Blue cheese with crackers</option>
        <option>Steak</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</label></p>
<input type="button" id="id-btn" value="Button">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) attribute selector

```
$('[id^=ddl]')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

**Alternative solution-**

A consistent solution is to add a common class to each of the dropdown elements & use

```
$('.commonDropDownClass')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

But you can use the first one if html markup is not in your hands & cannot change it for some reason.